# Should i put variables in window.document or use global context?

Tags: javascript, api

I have a variable **api** in which I have more methods that I want to use in **test** variable and both are in global context.

I think it would be better if I put them on window.document and I wonder what other options could be.

```
var api = (function(){

  this.run= function(){
    console.log("run api");
  };

  return this;

})();
```

// test is in separate file

```
var test = (function(one_){

  this.as = function(){
    console.log(one_.run());
  };


  return this;

})(one);


test.as();
```

Comment: ***Never*** put something on the `document` object. Global scope (== `window` object) as you currently have it is fine.

Comment: the document object isn't cleaned after each refresh or entering on a new page ?  
that's why i wanted to use the document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's little difference IMHO between dropping stuff in the global namespace (i.e. `window`) and `window.document`.

Sometimes (particularly when accessing variables from multiple source modules) you just *have* to create a global variable, so when you do, use namespaces to encapsulate your variables, leaving the namespace itself as the only leaked variable:

Module 1:

```
var BOGDAN = BOGDAN || {};
BOGDAN.api = ...
```

Module 2:

```
var BOGDAN = BOGDAN || {};
BOGDAN.test = ...
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. always is better to have more alternatives

Answer (score 4):

```
var company = company || {} ;

company.doSomething = function() {
};

company.test = {};
company.test.submodule = {};
company.test.submodule.doSomething = function() {};

company.api = {};
company.api.submodule = {};
```

You should generally avoid defining variables globally. For clear maintainable code, use objects as namespaces and avoid polluting the global namespace.

This also greatly enhances default JS functionality. If you are really keen on it, add something like `require.js` to your projects and you will get a very nice Java-like functionality.

So with `require.js`, your `company.api` and `company.test` can be placed in different files and `require` each other, just like you would do an `import company.test` with a Java `package`.

**Namespacing is a very efficient practice. You get:**

1. Readability(the most important thing in the world!!).
2. Maintainability.
3. Faster debugging.
4. Faster upgrades.
5. Efficient division of logic and functionality.
6. Prevents IE `window` vs `global` object bugs.
7. Makes working in a team possible and pleasant.
8. Speeds up development **A LOT**. Most IDEs will index and autofill your namespace objects.
9. You can effectively use jsDoc tags to document your JavaScript code.

**Important**

It it also fairly dangerous to use `this` in static contexts. JavaScript naming conventions dictate that static will be named starting with lower-case char and classes will be defined starting with an uppercase char, use camelCase of course.

Again, a very powerful and useful convention. It tells a developer that something is static or a class in the blink of an eye. So for instance, if you have:

```
company.test.submodule.doSomething = function() {
    // this is a static function. It's a normal property, it's not nested under the prototype.
};
```

Instead if you want to make a class, you can use the `this` reference in the correct way.

```
   // Notice Person starts with uppercase P.
company.test.subModule.Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numberOfEyes = 2;
};
company.test.subModule.Person.prototype.cryMeARiver = function() {
    console.log(this.name + " can cry a river.");
};
```

Now inside whatever other function, you can do:

```
company.api.someSubModule.peopleCryRivers = function() {
    // this is again a static context.
    var bodgan = new company.test.subModule.Person("Bogdan");
    var andreea = new company.test.subModule.Person("Andreea");
    bodgan.cryMeARiver();// will output "Bogdan can cry a river."
    andreea.cryMeARiver();// will output "Andreea can cry a river."
    // etc..
};
```

Comment: i totally agree with you, i have to do this because i want to call the method from my objects on some events from Iceface components.

    onBlur="test.run()"

Comment: i use a self invoking function where i passed the "one" as parameter. For the application that i'm working at, istead of "one" i pass jQuery cause i want inside of my function to use $ instead jQuery.

    validation.api = (function($){
    
       //code
    })(jQuery);

btw very interesting your example :)

Answer (score 1):

Attaching variables to `window.document` doesn't make sense to me, while attaching them to `window` is the same as declaring in the global namespace.

You can create (a global) variable as a namespace and attach your other variables to this.

```
var APP = {};
APP.api = ...
```

This of course runs the risk of conflicting with another object named 'APP'.

Another option is the simply wrap your variables within an Immediately Invoked Function Expression.

```
(function() {
    var api = ...
}();
```

This will scope them within the IIFE, where they cannot create conflicts. It also means that as your variables go out of scope they will be eligible for garbage collection.